# Why floating point formats in Mbed Studio don't work?

Tags: c, printf, mbed

```
float lgt = light.read();
if(isnan(lgt)){
    printf("Failed to read light!");
}
 else{
    printf("%f\n",lgt);
}
```

Second printf always print '%f' in the console instead of 'lgt' value. Why could this happen? I'm using Mbed Studio.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mbed+print+float ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why floating point formats in Mbed Studio don't work?

Because you are compiling your program with newlib nano version that does not support floating point format in `printf` family.